# react 400 bad request error.. I following the burger project and cant pass ingredients data from <Checkout/> to <ContactData/>

Tags: reactjs, firebase, axios, bad-request

class Checkout extends Component {
state={
ingredients: null,
price:0
}
componentWillMount(){
const query= new URLSearchParams(this.props.location.search);
const ingredients = {};
let price=0;
for(let param of query.entries()){
if(param[0] === 'price'){
price = param[1];
}
else{
ingredients[param[0]] = +param[1];
}

```
    }
    this.setState({ingredients: ingredients, totalPrice: price});
    }
checkoutCancelHandler = () => {
    this.props.history.goBack();
}
checkoutContinueHandler = () => {
    this.props.history.replace('/checkout/contact-data');
    }
render(){
    return(
        <div>
        <CheckoutSummary 
        ingredients={this.state.ingredients}
        checkoutCancelled={this.checkoutCancelHandler}
        checkoutContinued={this.checkoutContinueHandler}/>
```

<Route
path={this.props.match.path + '/contact-data'}
render={(props) => (<ContactData ingredients={this.state.ingredients} price={this.state.totalPrice} {...props} />)} />

```
        </div>
   );
}
```

}
export default Checkout;

Comment: Please add some description.

Comment: No one is going to read that code if it's so badly formatted please re format the code by editing the question